# Simulator and Storyboard Preview Difference

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, xcode6-beta6

Currently, I'm using Xcode 6 Beta 6 for this thread. I have this single view application for iOS 8.0 and iPhone devices only. That single view have the value `Inferred` under the `Attribute Inspector` > `Simulated Metrics`.

At first I didn't try to apply the `Add Missing Constraints` since I'm trying to layout the view to support a single layout both for 3.5" and 4" display. After running the current view - WYSIWYG on the simulator. That's fine and correct. When I tried to apply `Add Missing Constraints`, the changes applied to the base storyboard as well as to the device previews. But when I tried to run the application on the simulator, it wasn't the same.

What went wrong here?