# Xcode 6. Class Sizes, looks completely different at run time than on Interface Builder and preview

Tags: xcode

Similar to [Simulator and Storyboard Preview Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526774/simulator-and-storyboard-preview-difference)

From left to right: **Storyboard, Storyboard-Preview, Simulator/Device**

[image: image of layouts]

I've spent a lot of time making this work in all sizes ([Any,Any],[Compact,Any],[Regular,Regular] etc...), all looks good in 'Preview' (which I **thought** was supposed to simulate run time) and having it all looks completely different on Simulator/Device.

I've removed all constraints and rebuild many times. Using "Reset To Suggested Constraints.." is a complete mess (use to work perfectly), I've add them manually.

If a visual tool is so unpredictable, what else can I do other than go back to using two storyboards?