# Autolayout only installs selected phone size

Tags: ios8, autolayout, xcode6

I have an autolayout xib with Size Classes enabled. The view looks great in all the phone sizes under "Simulated Metrics" but when I install the app on the phone only the last layout that was selected under "Simulated Metrics" gets loaded. For example, if I choose iPhone 5.5-inch under simulated metrics and install it on an iPhone 4S the layout the iPhone 5.5-inch gets installed on the 4S, making it go off the screen.

Is there a setting or something I've messed up which says to only build the currently selected layout?

Comment: Look at my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140965/xcode-6-class-sizes-looks-completely-different-at-run-time-than-on-interface-b . I found myself reverting projects to pre-auto layout as Xcode 6 seems to be very unpredictable. After many hours, thinking I was was doing something wrong, I realised it's just not working as it should. Nothing I did short of running the project was reliable.

Comment: This is still broken. Any other thoughts?